# Javascript call AFTER redirect in phonegap using java script function?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

This is a function that I am Calling to redirect to specific page in phonegap Android platform app.

```
function redirect(){  
   var strr = "example.html";
   window.location="index.html";
   setTimeout("someJSfromSomething(strr)",5000);  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. And if it can, then it should not be done, for the following reason:

When the page is redirected (or refreshed), the old page is gone. The JavaScript code is evaluated in the context of the old page. If you can still run the code after its host page is dead, then you have a "runaway", or "ghost" script. In hacking terms, you have a "persistent" script that can be potentially used to breach the security. A well designed browser should not allow such script to stay alive, or allocate it any resource to execute. In fact, modern browsers all do this. For this very reason, PDF and Flash plugins are exploited to keep the script running.

I hope I have convinced you what you are asking is not possible. However, you can still have a solution by not refreshing the page. If the index page is your own page, wrap the entire page in a div container and use an Ajax load.

Comment: Ya i convinced but if I will load that page using Ajax Load then the jquery plug-ins that are linked with those page will load or not.

Comment: See if you have a native xmlHTTPRequest object. If so, you just need that one function to load the content and inject into a DIV. If you are looking for a lighter library, try this: http://www.antradar.com/docs-nano-ajax-manual

Comment: Ya i see that documentation but it will not solve my problem because it will not load the jquery plug-in linked on my page so that i want to reload it.

Comment: If it's an issue with referenced resource, then you can copy and paste the functions in nano.js. The library is tiny for this very reason. If the XHR object is not running for either security or compatibility reason then you might have to resort to hacks like iframe.